# Linux group quota for root user?

Tags: linux, root, quota

If I set a group quota on a folder, it seems that the hard limit can be exceeded if root write something into this folder. By the way, this one is owned by root.

I have added root to the group associated to this quota, nothing change.

Is root affected by group quota or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically every user with the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability is exempt from the check, and the root *user* classically has that capability. Being in the root group however is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks. My folder is owned by root and has the group GRP1. Root has been added to GRP1. But hard limit can be exceeded by root.